# How do I wrap classes around taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I need to add CSS to individual terms for a taxonomy field.  Where is the best place to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7).

This will allow you to customize the output of your term page.

Comment: Depending on the term, I want to apply different CSS attributes.  Would I do this in preprocess_taxonomy_term() ?

Comment: I suppose you could. If you code your theme properly, you'll always get unique id's on divs.

Comment: Where would I do that in preprocess_taxonomy_term?  I think the tpl file is fine if it's just dumping out what's handed to it...

Comment: Found it.  I just add it to the classes_array field.

Comment: Excellent, good to hear you found it!